# Thread Throwing Exceptions On JButton Press

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime-error, jbutton

So I have this program which is the base for a sort of "Cookie Clicker" like game, and I have managed to figure out how to make it keep a tally of the total clicks the player has made, as well as an idle clicker. However, when I want to make the program do more idle clicks per second by clicking on the JButton, except Java throws this error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
at counter_game.Counter$4.actionPerformed(Counter.java:111)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is what the program looks like. It uses a separate class just for running the addition on the program.

```
public class Counter 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.print(" ");

    Modifiers runtime = new Modifiers();

    Font font = new Font("Veranda", Font.BOLD, 14);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    Container pane = new Container();
    pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    JTextArea display = new JTextArea();
    display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));;
    display.setFont(font);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = .5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    pane.add(display, c);

    Thread idleThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                runtime.idleClick();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception c){}
                display.setText("Dollars:  $" + runtime.getTotal());
            }
        }
    };

    JButton clicker = new JButton();
    clicker.setText("Click Me!");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
    c.weightx = .5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    clicker.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            runtime.clicked();
            display.setText("Dollars:  $" + runtime.getTotal());
        }
    });
    pane.add(clicker, c);

    JButton multiplier = new JButton();
    multiplier.setText("+1 $/click");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = .5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    multiplier.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            runtime.multiply();
        }
    });
    pane.add(multiplier, c);

    JButton idle = new JButton();
    idle.setText("+1 $/sec");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = .5;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    idle.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            runtime.idle();
            idleThread.start();
        }
    });
    pane.add(idle, c);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(pane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}

{

public class Modifiers 

public Modifiers()
{
    total = 0;
    multiply = 0;
    idle = 0;
}

public void clicked()
{
    total = total + (1 + multiply);
}

public void multiply()
{
    multiply = multiply + 1;
}

public void idle()
{
    idle = idle + 1;
}

public void idleClick()
{
    total = total + idle;
}

public int getTotal()
{
    return total;
}

private int total;
private int multiply;
private int idle;
}
```

So the problem has something to do with the "idle" button being pressed more than once. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In `idleThread`, that `while-loop` will run for eternity. Did you do that on purpose or you need that loop to be break at one point..?

Answer (score 2):

You can't start a given thread more than once. Your code calls start on the same thread object every time that the button is pressed, causing the IllegalStateException. You need to reconsider how you're doing multithreading here.

By the way, be aware Swing components are not thread-safe and calling methods on them from a thread other than the event dispatch thread is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot.